# WiFi Direct Image Sharing on peer device in Android

Tags: android, p2p, file-transfer, wifi-direct

I have successfully implemented the wifi direct sample demo and the two way image sharing is working properly but my issue is when one device A sends an invitation to connect to device B and device B cancel that invitaion, i am not able to handle this cancel callback for that event as it is Android generated.

Anybody who can help me in resolving me issue.

Following is my broadcast reciever code and connect code :

```
/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important wifi p2p events.
 */
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WiFiDirectActivity activity;

    /**
     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
     * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
     */
    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
            WiFiDirectActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
            } else {
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
                activity.resetData();

            }
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));
            }
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P peers changed");
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            if (manager == null) {
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                // we are connected with the other device, request connection
                // info to find group owner IP

                DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) activity
                        .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
                manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, fragment);
            } else {
                // It's a disconnect
                activity.resetData();
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                    WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));

        }
    }
}
```

For connection i used the following code:

```
 WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
        config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
        config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
      device.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
        device.groupOwnerIntent = 0; // I want this device to become the owner
        manager.connect(channel, device, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The class needs to implement ConnectionInfoListener. And in the function onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) you can check if a successful connection has been established or not. The info argument of type WifiP2pInfo contains the information about the connection. It contains a boolean called groupFormed which indicates if a p2p group has been successfully formed. You can also retrieve from it if the device is groupOwner and the IP of the groupOwner, etc.

@Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {

```
    // After the group negotiation, we check if this device 
    // is acting as group owner

    if (info.groupFormed && !info.isGroupOwner) {

        // Do whatever you want the group owner to do

    } else if (info.groupFormed) {
        // The device now act as the slave device, 
        // and the other connected device is group owner
}
```

Google provides a very good demo app that uses WiFi Direct to send an image between 2 devices. Check its implementation and try to build on top of it. Link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Got it from:

[Check whether android wifip2p connection was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445560/check-whether-android-wifip2p-connection-was-successful)